# Delphi: form as passive UI during externally controlled processing

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, delphi-7

In a Delphi forms app, how can I get processing code to execute without user input, and how do I get the UI to update with a given frame rate?

The code in question is a test frame for testing/measuring the concurrent operation of components under heavy load, with multiple processes on the same or different machines. The focus is mostly on database operations (peer-to-peer or server-based) and filesystem reliability/performance with regard to file and byte range locking, especially over the network with heterogeneous client OSes.

The frame waits for external events (IPC, file system, network) that signal start and stop of a test run; after the start signal it calls the provided test function in a tight loop until the stop signal is received. Then it waits for the next start signal or the signal to quit.

I've been doing similar things in FoxPro for ages. There it is easy because the Fox doesn't have to sit on a message pump like Delphi's Application.Run(); so I just put up a non-modal form, arrange for it to be refreshed every couple hundred milliseconds and then dive into the procedural code. In raw Win16/Win32 it was slightly less easy but still fairly straightforward.

In Delphi I wouldn't even begin to know where to look, and the structure of the documentation (D7+XE2) has successfully defied me so far. What's the simplest way to do this in Delphi? I guess I could always spin up a new thread for the actual processing, and use raw Win32 calls like RedrawWindow() and PostQuitMessage() to bend the app to my will. But that looks rather klunky. Surely there must be 'delphier' ways of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a background thread to do the processing task. That leaves the main UI thread free to service its message loop as required.

Any information that the task needs to present to the user must be synchronized or queued to the main UI thread. Of course, there's plenty more detail required to write the complete application, but threading is the solution. You can use a high level library to shield yourself from the raw threads, but that doesn't change the basic fact that you need to offload the processing to a thread other than the main UI thread.

Comment: OK, so I give the form a method for recomputing any displayed values and then schedule it to be run on the UI thread at regular intervals corresponding to the frame rate, via e.g. TThread.Queue(). Will that cause the changed control contents to become visible (as it does in FoxPro) or does there have to be some additional call like Refresh() or Redraw()?

Comment: The refreshing will happen automatically because you won't be blocking the main UI thread.

Comment: Instead of having the task drive updates, have the UI take charge of that. Have the task provide the data, and have the UI consume it when it decides to. You've got used to the task driving the UI because FoxPro doesn't have threads. But once threads are available, you should think differently.

Comment: The logic has always been the same, in non-preemptive Win16, in multithreaded Win32 and in Fox, in .asm, .cpp, .pas and .prg: `if FrameTimeElapsed() and ValuesHaveChanged() then PerformVisualUpdate()`. Means and ways differ wildly, of course, but it always boils down to the moral equivalent of a WM_TIMER coupled with InvalidateRect() or RedrawWindow(). In Delphi the question becomes 'how do I get the UI thread to perform a period check à la UpdateVisualsIfNecessary()', without creating a third thread that's sleeping at the desired frame rate just in order to pulse the whole shebang?

Comment: Why a third thread ? Just check a sort of `Updated` flag that will be set if something changes in your data in the timer event.